# Iframe embedded youtube video not working on android?

Tags: android, html, iframe, youtube

I have the following piece of code :

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OZOX5sad2FE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works good on desktop, but when opened on a android device, the following message appears:

> Do you want to download the following file OZOX5sad2FE ?
>   YES/BLOCK

Clicking YES or BLOCK and the iframe is empty, there`s nothing there ..

What is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Desktop gonna work always (if its update).. But maybe your device is not compatible on browser with YTB.. Did u try to load youtube video on another website where is embedd code (iframe) from YTB ? ..